# how can get difference between a defined date and the dates from a csv file python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

I have a list of dates and I want to get a difference from a defined one(I mean days) and append days calculated in a new column

```
from datetime import date, datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("date.csv", parse_dates = ["dates"])

#a date to substact dates in csv
defined_date = date(2020,12,25)

#a list of dates from a csv file
csv_dates = df.dates

diff = [defined_date  - csv_dates]
print(diff)
```

I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'datetime.date'`

Now how can I read the dates in csv file in the same format as the defined date is there a way to do so

```
#How to change a list of dates from a csv file to date datatype
csv_dates = df.dates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because you are trying to subtract array(series) from `defined_date`. Which doesn't work like that. You need to iterate over your `csv_dates` series and add differences to the new column.

```
dates_diff = []
for d in csv_dates:
    dates_diff.append(d.date() - defined_date)

df['diff'] = dates_diff
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare an array with single variable, `'DatetimeArray'` means it is a Pandas timestamp array.

Just in a simple case, I am assign index `[0]` to the `csv_dates`.

At this point Pandas will give `Timestamp` object, we need to convert it to `datetime.date` using `.date()`

Here is working example.

My CSV file:

```
dates
2017/01/30
2017/01/30
2017/01/30
2017/01/30
2017/01/30
2017/01/30
```

### First approach, Converting `pandas.Timestamp` to `datetime.date`

Modified script:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("date.csv", parse_dates = ["dates"])

#a date to substact dates in csv
defined_date = date(2020,12,25)

#a list of dates from a csv file
csv_dates = df.dates

diff = [defined_date  - csv_dates[0].date()]
print(diff)
```

Result:

```
[datetime.timedelta(days=1425)]
```

### Edit: Second approach, Converting `datetime.date` to `pandas.Timestamp`

Change the datetime to pandas timestamp using `pd.to_datetime()`, and do all at once.

```
from datetime import date, datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("date.csv", parse_dates = ["dates"])

#a date to substact dates in csv
defined_date = pd.to_datetime(date(2020,12,25))

#a list of dates from a csv file
csv_dates = df.dates

diff = [defined_date  - csv_dates]
print(diff)
```

Result:

```
[0   1425 days
1   1425 days
2   1425 days
3   1425 days
4   1425 days
5   1425 days
Name: dates, dtype: timedelta64[ns]]
```

Comment: what if i have more than one series of dates in csv file since `csv_dates[0].date()` give out a days for the first date in a csv file

Comment: You can use loop to iterate over all dates

Comment: @ubongo This answer may fix the error. But looping over your data one at a time becomes slow when data grows.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling so what will be the best solution

Comment: @ubongo I don't know about best but this is faster https://stackoverflow.com/a/68633695/383793

Answer (score 1):

This error is shown because the data types of `csv['date']` and `defined_date` are different.

when you use `pd.read_csv("date.csv", parse_dates = ["dates"])` to read_csv file the date will parsing as `Timestamp`.

you need to change the type of dates from pandas dataframe using `date()`.

Therefore you can use the following code:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("date.csv", parse_dates = ["dates"])

#a date to substact dates in csv
defined_date = date(2020,12,25)

#a list of dates from a csv file
csv_dates = df.dates


df['diff'] = [defined_date  - csv_dates.date()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that you are working with different date types.

If you try this example:

```
defined_date = date(2020,12,25)
csv_dates = date(2020,12,28)

diff = defined_date - csv_dates
print(diff)
```

Output:

```
-3 days, 0:00:00
```

It Works.

So, you must convert your `csv['date']` according to the `defined_date` format.(or viceversa)